# Android spinner not changing in style

Tags: java, android, xml

So I have the spinner working and it works fine, but I can't change any of the styles except the background color in the activity_main.xml

First one is the simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/text1"
          style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="48dp"
          android:background="@color/app_primary"
          android:ellipsize="marquee"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
/>
```

Second one is simple_dropdown_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/text1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:background="@color/app_primary"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textStyle="normal"
 />
```

Comment: what do you exactly want to do ? can you be more specific ?

Comment: Change the background color and text color for starters

Comment: can't you change these attributes `android:textColor="@color/white"` , `android:background="@color/app_primary"` to achieve what you want ?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why. I can change it here `<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/turquoise"
                />` in the acitivty_main but it only changes the background color

Comment: can you add your activity code where you added adapter for your spinner ?

Comment: `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.time_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: and in your question which one is `R.layout.simple_spinner_item` ?

Comment: The second layout

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the dropdown list items you will need to create a new layout file. Let’s call it spinner_dropdown_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textColor="#aa66cc"/>
```

Another change in the declaration of the spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Try this**, hope it help